# Hanging kafka-producer-network-thread preventing app from exiting

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an app that uses KafkaStreams and writes updates to a downstream database (Redis). When that downstream database service goes down, the app attempts to gracefully shutdown; however, it gets to the end of the main() and just hangs due to unclosed network threads from Kafka. I can confirm from the logs that KafkaStreams was shutdown using kafkaStreams.close():

```
2020-08-07 14:40:54.723  INFO 1 --- [  shutdown-hook] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [imc1-retrospect-processor-v34-31881bef-a717-4d63-b548-5c4754329f1f] Already in the pending shutdown state, wait to complete shutdown
2020-08-07 14:40:54.723  INFO 1 --- [  shutdown-hook] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [imc1-retrospect-processor-v34-31881bef-a717-4d63-b548-5c4754329f1f] Streams client stopped completely
```

I am also logging the call stack for all active JVM threads after those above log messages, and I get fifteen of these:

```
Thread kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-15
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:794)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:467)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:335)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:244)
2020-08-07 14:40:54.721  INFO 1 --- [           main] <my_app>   :  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anyone help explain this behavior? Is this a bug in kafkaStreams.close()? I am also confused, why does it look like a producer thread is polling; shouldn't polling only be done by kafka consumer threads?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `KafkaStreams#close(Duration)` instead, to specify a timeout for `close()`. By design, `close()` (without parameters) blocks.

There are some known issue with regards to `close()` and timeouts thought:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9398
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7996

Also note, that in the stacktrace shows `NetworkClient.poll` that is totally different method than `Consumer.poll`.